# 500 response from sms.botframework.com/api/sms through Twilio

Tags: twilio, botframework

I've got a bot up and running, most of the time it is working ok, but Twilio throws some 500 and [502 errors](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200) on every inbound SMS.

```
An attempt to retrieve content from https://sms.botframework.com/api/sms returned the HTTP status code 500.
```

or

```
An attempt to retrieve content from https://sms.botframework.com/api/sms returned the HTTP status code 502.
```

The 502 requests continue fine and responses are sent, but the 500s do not - the user doesn't get a response.

How can i get logging from the sms.botframework.com service to see what's going on? No errors are showing on the azure side for my bot.

Thank you

Comment: I would love to help, but I can't find reference to the sms.botframework.com service anywhere. Could you share a link to the documentation on how you're using botframework and any code you're using? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, yeah, it's not really documented. But when you use the bot connector to hook up your published bot to the SMS channel, it uses twilio. That sms.botframework.com url is referenced during the steps for that process. It's not referenced in my code, it's referenced only in the twilio integration.

Comment: Where are you seeing these errors? Is this as reported in the [Monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor) section of your Twilio account?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the Bot Framework isn't set up for you to be able to get to the logs inside our SMS connector; the 502's are benign, but the 500's aren't something I normally see.  If you wish, you can contact me with your botid at bf-reports@microsoft.com and I'll take a look, or DM me on twitter (@jameslew).

@Philnash happy to fill you in more on the BotFramework and how developers can use it with Twilio; just let us know how to contact you.