# When connecting Twillio to my Bot, the Twilio device gets 404 when trying to post received sms

Tags: twilio, bots, botframework

I connected Twilio connector to my registered Bot.
Whenever I send a sms to my Twilio number, I can see in the logs that Twilio service gets 404 when trying to post a message to
https://sms.botframework.com/api/sms

The bot itself works well. I can test it with the webchat iframe or through the test console. But it seems that the Twilio integration to the bot framework is broken

[image]

Comment: I am having this same issue, were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here. I've just been through the process and was able to get my messages sent to & from my bot.

The fact that your unable to do that suggests you missed a step in the configuration, so I will try and describe what I did here to see if it helps you out.

1. Created a TwiML application [here](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/messaging/dev-tools/twiml-apps/add) and set its messaging url to https://sms.botframework.com/api/sms
2. Purchased a phone number and changed the messaging section to use my TwiML app.
3. Added my twilio credentials and twilio phone number to the SMS config section as follows:

[image]

One thing I noticed is that when Twilio makes a request to this URL to send an SMS, the url returns a 502.

[image]

But [according to a Microsoft employee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522990/500-response-from-sms-botframework-com-api-sms-through-twilio) this is "harmless".

Let me know if this helps you at all, or if you still need any help.

Comment: Marcos I am having the same issue of a 404 but I have gone through the configuration steps multiple times and still having an issue

Comment: My bot has been running for months then late last night the Twilio channel stopped working. I am getting the same 404. Any way to resolve this?